# how to split a float into two integers in C

Tags: c, format-specifiers

Below I am trying to set a format specifier, but I want to do it differently each time I call the function. The point is to print the float Data_Ave. In one instance I want the specifier %2.3f, and so I would pass the function a 2 for sig_figs_before and a 3 for sig_figs_after. In the next instance I want %1.4f, so I would pass those ints.

```
char * Send_Data(float Data[10], const char* SUBJECT_SEND_NAME, char *Data_Backup, int sig_figs_before, int sig_figs_after)
{
  float Data_Ave = ((Data[0] + Data[1] + Data[2] + Data[3] + Data[4] +
            Data[5] + Data[6] + Data[7] + Data[8] + Data[9])/10);
  sprintf(msgBody,"%%i.%if, ", before_decimal, after_decimal, Data_Ave);
  ... //Some more code
  }
```

I'm pretty sure this will not work, so I was thinking to split the float into two ints and print it like so:

```
sprintf(msgBody,"%i.%i, ", int_value, decimal_value);
```

But I do not know how to properly split the float.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This will not work. Think about "2.03" which will lead to before_decimal=2 after_decimal=3 and combined 2.3.
I don't get what you want to do? Why not sprintf'ing the fload directly? There are ways to format these.

Answer (score 5):

You want:

```
sprintf(msgBody,"%*.*f, ", before_decimal+after_decimal+1, after_decimal, Data_Ave);
```

Note that you can use `*` to specify the width by an integer argument. Also note that in a format `%N.Mf`, `N` is the total size of printed number (including decimals, dot, sign, exponent, padding, etc.) and `M` is the decimal precision. This is why, in your case, the first number shall be `before_decimal+after_decimal+1` not `before_decimal` only.

Comment: or `sprintf(msgBody,"%0*.*f ",...` to pad with leading zeros.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sprintf` twice to obtain the results you want — once to obtain the format string, and then again to obtain your actual result.

```
sprintf(format, "%%%i.%if", before_decimal, after_decimal);
sprintf(msgBody, format, Data_Ave);
```

The first line will write, e.g. (for 2 and 3) `%2.3f` into `format`; the second line will operate on that format string to write `msgBody`.

You should also consider using `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`, especially since you're using potentially variable-length strings — don't want to cause a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)!

Comment: For this purpose, the `*` width and precision specifiers exist, which take an int argument. No need to construct a format.

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf()` does not provide a "significant figures before".

It does provide a *minimum* field width which can be derived from `sig_figs_before`, `sig_figs_after` and the value itself.

```
char * Send_Data(float Data[10], const char* SUBJECT_SEND_NAME, 
    char *Data_Backup, int sig_figs_before, int sig_figs_after) {

  assert(sig_figs_before >= 1);
  assert(sig_figs_after >= 0);

  float Data_Ave = ((Data[0] + Data[1] + Data[2] + Data[3] + Data[4] +
                     Data[5] + Data[6] + Data[7] + Data[8] + Data[9])/10);

  int width = sig_figs_before + 1 + sig_figs_after;  // +1 for '.'
  // Make room for '-'
  if (Data_Ave < 0) width++;
  sprintf(msgBody, "%#*.*f, ", width, sig_figs_after, Data_Ave);
}
```

`'#'` is used should `sig_figs_after == 0` to preserve the decimal point.

Note: this does not *limit* the width or the number of `sig_figs_before` should `Data_Ave` be large.  @Matt Patenaude idea to use `snprintf()` is a good one.

A hack approach would be to test:

```
if (log10(fabs(Data_Ave)+0.5) > sig_figs_before) UseAlternativePrint();
```